# NSComboBoxTableColumn

Tags: xcode, macos, class

I'm a newbie working on an open-source application whose creators haven't updated it since 2008.  One of the .nib files uses an `NSComboBoxTableColumn`, and I can't figure out how to find/replicate this.  Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: I could be wrong but that seems like a custom class.  Even with the NS in front of it there isnt a reference in the apple docs that i could find.  (googling that offered few results).  ios doesnt have combo boxes as far as i know, just switches.  I would say your going to have to hack it, either make that same class or replace it with something that looks right.

Comment: or maybe the original app was for osx?

Comment: Whoops.  Gave it the wrong tag.  Yeah, the original was for OSX, but I couldn't find anything, so my guess is you're right that it must be a custom class.  I don't understand why the class isn't part of the svn code, but there it is....